# WireMock recording in context of microservices - one client calling many servers

Tags: http, microservices, wiremock, wiremock-record

In my project, there are more than 100 microservices. In my case, I want to test my microservice independently from any other external service.

The scenario of my microservice "A" - *main number crunching microservice*, which I am targetting to test independently of other external services.
In my scenario Actor Request "A" to perform an action and then "A" get some data from "B" "D" "C" and perform complex logic and return a response back to Actor

[image]

To Test A independently, I intend to use **Wiremock** to **record** various **request-response** from A to other microservices (B, C, D)

As, I understood from Wiremock documentation, to use record feature of Wiremock we have to unable *--proxy-all* to *target services* with respect to the client and then request to host:port of Wiremock which is in-turn forward to actual service and request/response is recorded.

But in my case it is not possible as I am in the microservices world. Service "B", "C", "D" runs on random port and in my actual scenario A gets the address of B from Service Registry so even if I manually start many Wiremock with proxying target services still I would not be able to reproduce the request to wiremock (which in turn get proxied to respect service).

So how to record my desired request and response (from target microservice "A" to "B", "C" and "D".

Comment: Why is the Service Registry not mocked in your setup?

Comment: nothing is mocked right now, I want to capture response/response from the real interaction first. Once I have those recorded responses then mocking is the second step. I am stuck at first step only, how to record the above mentioned scenario.

Comment: Without any control over the Service Registry you won't be able to direct the requests 2,3,4 to any WireMock instance. So, unless you have that option in Service A, requests 2,3,4 are not recordable using WireMock.

Comment: That is exactly the problem I trying to solve. Isn't there any option in Wiremock to record, whatever passes through it. What I tried is set http.proxy as wiremock host:port at JVM level. Now automatically all the request is proxied through Wiremock in my JVM but even after enabling --record-mappings option nothing is getting recorded.